# Are voting systems on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, area51

There is a [new proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97790/voting-systems) in area 51 about voting systems.

Are questions on voting systems welcome here? Under what conditions?

Comment: There is a tag [tag:voting-theory] that is for the mathematical analysis of voting systems. My general guideline: If the question is primarily about the mathematics rather than the implementation, it ought to be fine here. Among the questions you've put in the suggestion, I'd say that *maybe* two of them are on-topic here, the one about other single-mark systems (borderline) and the one about the consistency criterion.

Comment: The question about an equivalent of Arrow’s theorem is certainly on-topic here. The question about causing maximum damage seems to me primarily mathematical and hence on-topic here. The question about what systems are least manipulable is probably too broad, but with a definition of *manipulable* and some limitation on the voting systems under consideration it *might* fit.

Comment: If the question is about whether new voting systems on stack exchange will work or about the math behind them, no. Such a question should be reserved for meta. However, voting systems in general probably don't belong explicitly on math stack exchange. Anything really could exist here. All sciences use math to some degree. So, a better thing to ask isn't if the subject belongs here, but rather /when/ the subject belongs here. After all, a site devoted to voting systems is probably better equipped in the same way a physics integral is best handed by the physics stack exchange section.